# Don't understand this isset behavior

Tags: php, mysql, session

Simple, I don't understand why it doesn't enter inside the IF when closing the session and opening with a different user.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['Username'])) {
  $_SESSION['Username'] = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
}
```

Only works the first time and remain with the same name even if I log out. I also closed the browser and I always get the same name. I thought that `$_SESSION['Username']` would be destroyed after closing the session.

Comment: Define closing the session

Comment: what are you doing at log out time for destroying session and closing browser may not destroy session.

Comment: You should explain what your problem realy is in more detail. People still think your session is not created insetad of not destroyed. Otherwise they will keep upvoting the wrong answer.

Comment: Oh and if your session was destroyed like you want, you would have MM_Username either. So there might be more going on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you have posted doesn't initiate the session:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['Username'])) {
  $_SESSION['Username'] = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
}
```

You need to tell apache to kick off session variables using [session_start](https://www.php.net/function.session-start) otherwise you can't access anything in it.

Additionally from memory, you will need to post this at the top of your script (before any data is sent to the user) - though this might not matter, I can't recall right now. Please edit if that statement is incorrect :)

Edit: If you *have* got this and it is functioning, you should use a [session_destroy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) when logging the user out to ensure that any data is wiped out from the session. This will mean you won't have to worry about closing the browser or anything like that:

```
// your logout script... and
session_destroy();
```

Comment: Didnt the OP state that he HAS a session. The problem is with destroying it, not getting it to work!

Comment: @ToBe Hmmm, seems to easy - but I made an edit and covered that point that you made - which was valid :) **tips hat**

Comment: I had the session_start() in all the pages, but not the session_destroy() on the logout.php file. I guess all you said make sense, but still don't get why is the data set for (SESSION['Username']) after changing to other session or even closing the browser. It's not what I read about the way SESSION variables works.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure that the session ends when your user logs out, use http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php .
Unintended results may occur if you assume the session will end after a certain amount of time or when the user closes a browser tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to unset all your $_SESSION variables you can do the following:

```
$_SESSION = array();
```